# Calculating for a point's reprojection error in Opencv(2D)

Tags: opencv, 2d, reprojection-error

I have already obtained the instrinsic parameters of the camera and I know the point's location `(x,y)`. However, I want get reprojection error on a image.
How can I get the location when some point is reprojected?

I tried to use the 'reconsturct' function, but I am not sure if this function will work the I want.

My `OpenCV` version is `4.3`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simpler than I thought.

When the coordinates of the points found in the image are called ( a,b ),

The difference between (a2, bx ) obtained by re-projecting the parameter obtained through caliberation ( a,b,1 ) by multiplying the coordinates by (a,b, 1).